# How can I get Distribute Points on Face to work on specific face?

Tags: geometry-nodes, faces

I have a plane, with slight thickness and I've used Geo nodes to put artifacts on it, however I only want them on a specific face and not clipping through the plane or anything like that. Marked in red is what I don't want.[image]

Answer (score 1):

there are many ways to do this, one possible way is this:

[image]

result:

[image]

The poisson Disk makes sure that the cubes don't overlap, if you set a distance min > 0.
The normal is the vector which describes the direction of the face, the so called "face direction" which is perpendicular to a planar face. If you split this normal vector into its components, you can compare the z value to 0, if this is bigger 0, then the normal points at least "a little bit up". That's enough to know because on a (non rotated cube, which is your plane) the normals for the side points sidewards, the lower face's normal points downwards and the upper faces's normal points upwards (which is what we want to filter).
The transform node before the instance on points node make sure that they "sit" correct on the plane.

If you want to have an answer for objects with different heights, please don't edit your question, but open a new question because you neither specify that nor did you provide a blend file and/or your node tree so that we could know that. You can ask as many questions as you want.